# Drop down menu hover is working but not able to click

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Drop down menu hover is working but not able to click.
Tried a lot of times, just couldn't sort out the problem..
My html code: (looks like it does not have have any error)

HTML:

```
    <ul id="menu-bar">
        <li class='active'><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>1</span></a>
            <ul>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>1-1</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>1-1-1</span></a></li>
                    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>1-1-2</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>1-2</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>1-2-1</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>1-2-2</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>1-2-3</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>1-2-4</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>1-2-5</span></a></li>
                    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>1-2-6</span></a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>1-3</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>1-3-1</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>1-3-2</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>1-3-3</span></a></li>
                    <li class='last'><a href="#"><span>1-3-4</span></a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>
           <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>1-4</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>1-4-1</span></a></li>
                    <li class='last'><a href="#"><span>1-4-2</span></a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>1-4</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>1-5</span></a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>1-6</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#menu-bar {
   width: 95%;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 6px 6px 4px 6px;
   height: 45px;
   line-height: 100%;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6E052E;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6E052E;
   -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6E052E;
   background: #FF0A6C;
   border: solid 1px #C40853;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 999;
}

#menu-bar li {
   margin: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
   padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   list-style: none;
}

#menu-bar li ul {
   display: none;
}

#menu-bar a {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-family: 'comic sans ms';
   font-style: normal;
   font-size: 25px;
   color: #FFBFDD;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   padding: 6px 20px 6px 20px;
   margin: 0;
   margin-bottom: 4px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
   text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6E052E;
}

#menu-bar li ul li a {
   margin: 0;
}

#menu-bar .active a,#menu-bar li:hover>a {
   background: #FFD4EC;
   color: #FF0088;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
   box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
   text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
}

#menu-bar ul li:hover a,#menu-bar li:hover li a {
   background: none;
   border: none;
   color: #666;
   -box-shadow: none;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   -moz-box-shadow: none;
}

#menu-bar ul a:hover {
   background: #FF0088 !important;
   color: #FFC9F1 !important;
   border-radius: 0;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0;
   -moz-border-radius: 0;
   text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #FFFFFF;
}

#menu-bar ul {
   background: #FFD4EC;
   display: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 190px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 45px;
   left: 0;
   border: solid 1px #FF8CB6;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6E052E;
   -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6E052E;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6E052E;
}

#menu-bar li:hover>ul {
   display: block;
}

#menu-bar ul li {
   float: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

#menu-bar ul a {
   padding: 10px 0px 10px 15px;
   color: #FF0088 !important;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-style: normal;
   font-family: arial;
   font-weight: normal;
   text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
}

#menu-bar ul li:first-child>a {
   border-top-left-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
   border-top-right-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
}

#menu-bar ul li:last-child>a {
   border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
}

#menu-bar:after {
   content: ".";
   display: block;
   clear: both;
   visibility: hidden;
   line-height: 0;
   height: 0;
}

#menu-bar {
   display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] #menu-bar {
   display: block;
}

* html #menu-bar {
   height: 1%;
}
```

Comment: Post your css too please.

Comment: Kindly post your css and html in a fiddle.

Comment: Can you add any CSS and JS as well?

Comment: #menu-bar {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 6px 6px 4px 6px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6E052E;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6E052E;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6E052E;
  background: #FF0A6C;
  border: solid 1px #C40853;
  position:relative;
  z-index:999;
}

Comment: #menu-bar li {
  margin: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
  padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu-bar li ul{
    display:none;
}

#menu-bar a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'comic sans ms';
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #FFBFDD;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 20px 6px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6E052E;
}

Comment: #menu-bar li ul li a {
  margin: 0;
}
#menu-bar .active a, #menu-bar li:hover > a {
  background: #FFD4EC;
  color: #FF0088;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
}
#menu-bar ul li:hover a, #menu-bar li:hover li a {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #666;
  -box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}

Comment: #menu-bar ul a:hover {
  background: #FF0088 !important;
  color: #FFC9F1 !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-bar ul {
  background: #FFD4EC;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 190px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 0;
  border: solid 1px #FF8CB6;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6E052E;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6E052E;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6E052E;
}

Comment: #menu-bar li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}


#menu-bar ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu-bar ul a {
  padding:10px 0px 10px 15px;
  color:#FF0088 !important;
  font-size:12px;
  font-style:normal;
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-bar ul li:first-child > a {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
}

Comment: #menu-bar ul li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
}
#menu-bar:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#menu-bar {
  display: inline-block;
}
  html[xmlns] #menu-bar {
  display: block;
}
* html #menu-bar {
  height: 1%;
}

Comment: I don't even know how to post a proper css code here.. hopefully any kind soul could help me solve my problem!! Thank you very much, sincerely~

Comment: You can edit your post and include css code there :)

Comment: Skynet, your edit just added a tag to the question, you could have been more helpful editing it posting the CSS provided by Zixin Xi, I think your edit was nonsense

Answer (score 1):

You could add this for your sub sub menu.

```
#menu-bar li li:hover > ul {
    left: 190px;
    top: 0;
}
```

And place your submenu higher so you can acces it.

```
#menu-bar ul {
    background: #ffd4ec;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 190px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 0;
    border: solid 1px #ff8cb6;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6e052e;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6e052e;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #6e052e;
}
```

See http://jsbin.com/fixaperunone/1/edit

Comment: @ZixinXi just in case I used stylus to parse your CSS in my post below, it may not be in the same order you have.

Comment: @ZixinXi If it works, maybe you can mark it as the correct answer.